# Matplotlib: Points do not show in SVG

Tags: python, svg, matplotlib

I have a scatter plot that I'd like to output as SVG (Python 3.5). However, when used with `agg` as backend, some points are simply missing. See the data and the PNG and SVG output. Is this some kind of misconfiguration or a bug?

Code:

```
import matplotlig
matplotlib.use('agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [22752.9597858324,33434.3100283611,None,None,3973.2239542398,None,None,None
,None,None,None,None,None,960.6513071797,None,None,None,None,None,None,None
,None,None,None,None,None,749470.931292081,None,None,None,None,None,None
,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,23045.262784499,None,None,None
,None,None,None,None,1390.8383822667,None,None,9802.5632611025
,3803.3240362092,None,None,None,None,None,2058.1191666219,None
,3777.5383953988,None,91224.0759036624,23296.1857550166,27956.249381887
,None,237247.707648005,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None
,760.3493458787,None,321687.799104496,None,None,22339.5617383239,None,None
,None,None,None,28135.0261453192,None,None,None,None,None,None,None
,1687.4387356974,None,None,29037.8494868489,None,None,None,None,None,None
,None,3937.3066755226,None,None,None,None]
y = [63557.4319306279,None,None,None,9466.0204228915,None,None,None,None,None
,None,None,None,3080.3393940948,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None
,None,None,None,None,592184.803802073,None,None,None,None,None,None,None
,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,18098.725166318,None,None,None,None
,None,None,None,789.2710621298,None,None,7450.9539135753,4251.6033622036
,None,None,None,None,None,1277.1691956597,None,4273.5950324508,None
,51861.5572682614,19415.3369388317,2117.2407148378,None,160776.887146683
,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,1550.3003177484,None
,402333.163939038,None,None,16604.3340243551,None,None,None,None,None
,32545.0784355136,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,2567.9264180605,None
,None,45786.935597305,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,5645.5218715636
,None,None,None,None]
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x, y, '.')
fig.savefig('/home/me/test_svg', format='svg')
fig.savefig('/home/me/test_png', format='png')
```

The result:

PNG:

[image: PNG output]

SVG:

[image: SVG output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be related to the `None` values. Though there is simply no point included if no matching point exists, it seems to influence the rendering of the SVG. Removing both entries if at one or the other point is `None` fixes the issue.

```
data = np.array([x, y])
data = data.transpose()
# Filter out pairs of points of which at least one is None.
data = [pair for pair in data if pair[0] and pair[1]]
data = np.array(data).transpose()
x = data[0]
y = data[1]
ax.plot(x, y, '.')
fig.savefig('/home/me/test_svg', format='svg')
fig.savefig('/home/me/test_png', format='png')
```

Answer (score 1):

### Update

This looks like a bug that was fixed some time between matplotlib 2.0.0 and 3.1.1. Upgrading solved the problem for me.

### Original Answer

I ran into the same problem, so I created a minimal example to reproduce it:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

data = np.array([1.0, np.nan, 1.0])
plt.plot(data, 'o')
plt.savefig('example.svg')
plt.savefig('example.png')
```

It works fine as a PNG:

[image: working example as PNG]

However, the left point is missing from the SVG.

Using your suggestion of removing invalid data, I used the numpy indexing features:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

data = np.array([1.0, np.nan, 1.0])
indexes = np.arange(data.size)
is_valid = np.negative(np.isnan(data))
plt.plot(indexes[is_valid], data[is_valid], 'o')
plt.savefig('example.svg')
plt.savefig('example.png')
```

Now the PNG and the SVG display both points.